# Why cant we use the java based libraries in Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile when kotlin is interoperable with Java?

Tags: java, kotlin, libraries, kotlin-multiplatform

I want to understand why we only have to use libraries written in Kotlin and not in java in KMM when kotlin is completely interoperable with Java.

I was just watching the tutorials and they keep telling that we have to use kotlin libraries.

Comment: If you use Java libraries then how would you execute your application e.g. in iOS which doesn't support running Java code?

Comment: “kotlin is completely interoperable with Java.” — Kotlin/JVM is completely interoperable with Java; other Kotlin platforms aren't. (Kotlin/JVM was the first Kotlin platform, so older docs and tutorials may not draw the distinction.)